# How to set the size of the buffer for c# ReceiveAsync method

Tags: c#, tcpserver

I try to setup a server for a specific application.
So far I have made a test program like that:

```
Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
listener.Listen(10);
while (true)
{
    Socket clientSocket = await listener.AcceptAsync();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = await clientSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
    //Extract data from the buffer
}
```

The issue is that the size of the message I get from the client varies, but it contains its length in the first 4 bytes.
So, how can I read the first 4 bytes, set the size of the buffer and then read the complete message asynchronously?

Comment: it doesn't matter, the rest of the bytes are empty and don't ise up space

Comment: Just like you said: read the first 4 bytes which contain the length prefix, create a buffer of the desired size that's now know, and then read the message

Comment: It's exactly this part _then read the message_ I don't know how to do. Should I add another ReceiveAsync or another command? Does this command retrieve the rest of the data or the complete dataset?

Answer (score 0):

By continuing exploring how to get a solution to my request, I came up with the following.

```
/*The message I receive from the client is a list of datasets
    * which consists of an ident (1 float) and 10 floats of data (for simplicity in reality it's more)
    * The first 4 bytes are a float of the number of datasets in the packet
    */
float nbOfDataSets;
int index = 0;
int bytesRead = await clientSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
if (bytesRead > 0)
{
    //Getting the number of datasets
    nbOfDataSets = BitConverter.ToSingle(buffer, 0);

    //Calculation of the number of bytes in the received packet
    int nbOfDataFor1_Set = 11; //Ident + data
    totalOfBytes = (nbOfDataFor1_Set * (int)nbOfDataSets) * 4; // * 4 because 1 float consists of 4 bytes
    totalOfBytes += 4; //+4 for the first float representting the number of datasets 

    //Initialize the buffer that will contain the full packet
    bufferAll = new byte[totalOfBytes + 4]; //+4 for spare
    Array.Copy(buffer, bufferAll, bytesRead);
    index = bytesRead;

    while (index < totalOfBytes)
    {
        bytesRead = await clientSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
        Array.Copy(buffer, 0, bufferAll, index, bytesRead);
        index += bytesRead;
    }
//Extract data from bufferAll ...
}
```

I don't know if it's the right way to do it, but it seems to work